# AstronomicalData not including units?

Tags: curated-data, units, homework, astronomy

I like using mathematica to do my physics homework, and `AstronomicalData` is useful for that, but it doesn't seem to work properly with units.

[the question is, at what height is the gravitational acceleration 4.9 meters per second square
[image]

Is there a way to get AstronomicalData to output with units?

Comment: You should post actual code, not images.

Comment: If I were your teacher, I would frown on the large amount of data you "consume", and would appreciate a lean and mean `Solve[9.81*r^2 == 4.9*(r + \[Delta])^2, \[Delta]]` which results in `{\[Delta]->0.414935 r}` as positive solution. So 141.49% of earth's radius. But then again, tastes differ.

Comment: AstronomicalData is older than the units. But, from what we can see in the new WL documentation, they will start coming with units.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
m = Quantity[AstronomicalData["Earth", "Mass"], AstronomicalData["Earth", "Mass", "Units"]]
```

> ```
> 5.9721986*10^24 kg
> ```

```
m // FullForm
```

> ```
> Quantity[5.9721985999999999999999999999999999999999202`8.*^24,"Kilograms"]
> ```